# Using the quickfix python along with twisted

Tags: python, twisted, quickfix

I have used quickfix in c++. I am trying to use the python version.
Documentation seems a little sparse, so I was hoping to get some information regarding the same.
I have an emulator, that assembles a message in various protocols (some fix/ some non fix).
opens a tcp connection to a server and sends these messages over.
I am considering assembling the fix message using quickfix.
I don't want to use the client portion of quickfix, just the part which assembles a fix message. 
Can this be done? ie: does the api support getting the raw fix(which can then be sent over tcp connection) from Message format.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: What is "quickfix"?  Can you please provide some references, maybe some sample code?

Comment: @Glyph quickfix is an api to the Financial Information eXchange protocol.  Its for sending orders and data between financial institutions.

Comment: I am not familiar with the python API but I assume it should allow you to create a message object and have that ready to transmit.

Comment: Is quickfix open source?

Comment: @Glyph yes. it is open source. [offical page](http://quickfixengine.org/)

Comment: @Pradyot You can convert FIX.Message objects to string. But, there are other point like Sequence Numbers, HeaderFields, Field validations etc. What is your plan about these?

Answer (score 2):

Use the message.ToString() function to serialize the message.